# Chemical potential of a BEC

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, chemical-potential

I know that the chemical potential of a BEC can be calculated with $\mu=\frac{\partial E}{\partial N}$, where $E$ is the energy and $N$ is the number of particles. For the Gross-Pitaevskii equation with a time-dependent potential $V(x,t)$,

\begin{align}
i\hbar\dot\psi=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi+V(x,t)\psi^2+g\psi^4\ ,
\end{align}

we have the energy

\begin{align}
E=\int d^3x\left[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi+V(x,t)\psi^2+g\psi^4\right]
\end{align}

and $N=\psi^2$. Therefore, $\mu=g|\phi|^2+V(x,t)$. If $V(x,t)=V(x)$, the chemical potential is apparently a constant (according to (1.39) in [this thesis](https://books.google.ca/books?id=uDU3CwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Interferometry%20with%20interacting%20Bose-Einstein%20condensates%20in%20a%20double-well%20potential&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6xuakgpLiAhVNTd8KHT3TAbMQ6AEIKDAA#v=snippet&q=in%20general%2C%20the%20time-independent%20GPE%20cannot%20be%20solved%20analytically&f=false)), but I am unsure how to see that. Is $\mu$ still constant even with time-dependence incorporated into the potential, $V$? I know that I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I'm able to follow your train of thought. If $\mu=g|\phi|^2+V(x,t)$ (but I doubt there should be an $x$ in there), then $\mu$ is clearly time dependent because of the potential.

Comment: What does 'BEC' stand for?